# How to reference each _id in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections on my db.

At first i have "tvs" collection that have a list of tvs, at second i have tvcomments that holds the comments made in each tv.

I would like to update the "tvs" collection with a new field that shows the count of the comments from each tv.

The "tv" field is the "_id" field from "tvs" collection that references the commented tv.

I prove the code bellow but it isn´s works

```
db.tvs.update( { $set: { numcomments: db.tvcomments.find( { tv: this._id } ).count() } }, { multi: true } )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default `_id` keys in Mongo are Mongo Object IDs. You have to convert `this._id` into ObjectId: `ObjectId(this._id)`.

Your command becomes:

```
db.tvs.update( { $set: { numcomments: db.tvcomments.find( { tv: ObjectId(this._id) } ).count() } }, { multi: true } )
```

> ObjectId is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:
>
> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

See more information in [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/).